How to Simulate Concurrency in GJS?
I am trying to use aosd_cat to visually label each accessibility element on the linux desktop. I can spawn this command synchronously no issue, but cannot find a way to spawn this command in many times parallel to visualize every element at once (i.e. without blocking until the previous visualization finishes)
I also want to keep the list of each cancelHandle so I can cancel them all at once, when the GUI updates.
// condensed example with just relevant code
function paintScreen() {
  try {
    const cancelHandle = Gio.Cancellable.new();
    const proc = Gio.Subprocess.new(["aosd_cat"], Gio.SubprocessFlags.STDIN_PIPE);
    proc.communicate_utf8("LABEL_NAME", cancelHandle);
    
  } catch (e) {
    logError(e);
  }
}

I have tried using .communicate_async() or .wait_async() but neither seems to work and don't spawn the command, even if I await it.
In Python I would use threadpoolexecutor or something similar, but that is obviously not an option here.
I am not sure how to fix this. I would also like a solution that continues to let me pass stdin to the aosd_cat command. You can assume all my other code works fine.
I am compiling from TS to GJS using ts-for-gir if it matters
Thank you very much

The process starts when you call Gio.Subprocess.new(). It's hard to say without seeing what you tried, but you may have tried this:
await proc.communicate_utf8_async("LABEL_NAME", cancellable, callback);

Unless the function has been promisified, that won't return a Promise or wait on the result. You may try this, noting the "callback" parameter is omitted:
Gio._promisify(Gio.Subprocess.prototype, 'communicate_utf8_async',
    'communicate_utf8_finish');

async function paintScreen() {
  try {
    const cancelHandle = Gio.Cancellable.new();
    const proc = Gio.Subprocess.new(["aosd_cat"], Gio.SubprocessFlags.STDIN_PIPE);
    await proc.communicate_utf8_async("LABEL_NAME", cancelHandle);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

Otherwise you need to use a callback (which may be wrapped in a Promise manually):
function paintScreen() {
  const cancelHandle = Gio.Cancellable.new();
  const proc = Gio.Subprocess.new(["aosd_cat"], Gio.SubprocessFlags.STDIN_PIPE);
  proc.communicate_utf8_async("LABEL_NAME", cancelHandle, (_sourceObject, result) => {
    try {
      const [, _stdout, _stderr] = proc.communicate_utf8_finish(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
}

See also:

Asynchronous Programming in GJS
Subprocesses


Thank you very much. Unfortunately I am not finding that works. Nothing is spawned (i.e. colored on the screen), but the program completes as normal otherwise. I know the command works since the blocking versions works. I tried both examples you gave.
If it helps, I have a gist of the code here: https://gist.github.com/C-Loftus/1b4bbf627bcd1235c595aa36d5a4cb17 for the full version, which is still fairly simple.
I wonder if this is a ts or version issue.

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the application you're trying to spawn. You may be hitting this bug though: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/3310

No worries. I don't think this is specific to that application, moreso was just trying to get at the fact it seems not to be reading from stdin properly. So yup probably does seem to be that! Perhaps I will switch to python bindings instead for at-spi unless there is a better solution
